# require_relative from present working dir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I built a ruby gem with a binary. I use like this:

```
myruby "param"
```

It is a helper for building integration, and needs a setting for each project. I have settings in `settings.rb` for several projects. Is it possible to require a `.rb` file based on the present working dir? When I run:

```
/home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1/ $ myruby start
```

I want it to require the settings from:

```
/home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1/settings.rb
```

How could I do this if it's possible? I tried:

```
require_relative '#{Dir.pwd}/settings.rb'
```

which did not work.

Comment: have you use `bundler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
```

gives you the path to the current directory. Thus if you have a file in `bin/foo` and you want to require something in `lib/foo/settings.rb` simply use

```
require File.join(File.expand_path('../../'), __FILE__), 'lib/foo/settings.rb')
```

Note the double `../` because the first is required to strip out from `__FILE__` the current filename.

If the file is in `/home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1/bin/foo`

```
File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)
# => /home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1/bin
File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
# => /home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1
File.join(File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__), 'lib/foo/settings.rb')
# => /home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1/lib/foo/settings.rb
```

If you want to include the file with a relative path from the working directory, use

```
require File.join(Dir.pwd, 'settings.rb')
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to hard-code a path in this way. You may probably want to pass the settings as argument to the command line.

It doesn't really make sense to create a gem that depends on a path of a file hard-coded on your machine.

Comment: this returns "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/" unfortunally because i use my program from gem.

Answer (score 0):

`File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))` will return the directory relative to the file this command is called from.
The difference between `require` and `require_relative` is that `require_relative` loads files from directory relative to the file where it is written. While `require` searches for files in directories from `$LOAD_PATH` if given a relative path or can load files from absolute path, which can be created with `File.expand_path`

Comment: The executed file is in gems directory, what i get in return therefore is "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/" instead of "home/usr/admin/sources/myproject1"

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to get directory where `myruby` is run. If you are using Unix you can get current directory from `PWD` environment variable, using `ENV['PWD']` in ruby.